# How to optimize database queries when the create method is invoked?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I send a request to the database to read / write data saved from an exel file. The data are from 4 to 10 thousand lines of json format. I have encountered that the query lasts a very long time . It takes up to 20 seconds on the local compute (quite powerful), and on the server it takes more than a minute and eventually falls off with an error. It seems to me that there is not much data to make the request last so long.

the serializer `create` method looks like

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        # Get data from url context
        rfiid = self.context.get('rfiid')
        vendor_id = self.context.get('vendor')
        analyst_id = self.context.get('analyst')
        vendor = Vendors.objects.get(vendorid=vendor_id)
        round = Rfis.objects.get(rfiid=rfiid)
        current_scoring_round = self.context.get('current_scoring_round')

        # for update rfipartisipatiostatus analyst/vendor response (1 or 0)
        status_info = self.context.get('status_info')

        # save CI
        company_information = self.context.get('Company_info')
        for ci in company_information:
            ciq, _ = CompanyGeneralInfoQuestion.objects.get_or_create(question=ci.get('question'), rfi=round)
            cia, _ = CompanyGeneralInfoAnswers.objects.update_or_create(vendor=vendor, question=ciq,
                                                                        defaults={'answer': ci.get('answer')})

        # Get data from validated data
        sc = validated_data.pop('s')
        cat = validated_data.pop('category')
        pc = validated_data.pop('pc')
        self_score = validated_data.pop('self_score')
        self_description = validated_data.pop('self_description')
        sm_score = validated_data.pop('sm_score')
        analyst_notes = validated_data.pop('analyst_notes')
        attachment = validated_data.pop('attachment')

        parent_category = ParentCategories.objects.filter(parent_category_name=pc)
        if parent_category:
            category, _ = Categories.objects.get_or_create(category_name=cat, pc=parent_category.first())
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"general_errors": ["Parent categories are not exist"]})
        subcategory, _ = Subcategories.objects.get_or_create(subcategory_name=sc, c=category)

        rfi_part_status, _ = RfiParticipationStatus.objects.update_or_create(vendor=vendor, rfi=round,
                                                                             pc=parent_category.first(),
                                                                             defaults={'last_analyst_response': current_scoring_round,
                                                                                       'last_vendor_response': current_scoring_round}
                                                                             )

        element, _ = Elements.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data, s=subcategory)

        if analyst_id:
            analyst_notes, _ = AnalystNotes.objects.get_or_create(vendor=vendor, e=element, analyst_notes=analyst_notes,
                                                                  rfi=round, analyst_response=current_scoring_round)

            sm_scores, _ = SmScores.objects.get_or_create(vendor=vendor, e=element, sm_score=sm_score, rfi=round,
                                                          analyst_response=current_scoring_round)

            rfi_part_status, _ = RfiParticipationStatus.objects.update_or_create(vendor=vendor, rfi=round,
                                                                                 pc=parent_category.first(),
                                                                                 defaults={
                                                                                     'last_analyst_response': current_scoring_round}
                                                                                 )

        else:
            self_score, _ = SelfScores.objects.get_or_create(vendor=vendor, e=element, self_score=self_score, rfi=round,
                                                             vendor_response=current_scoring_round)

            self_description, _ = SelfDescriptions.objects.get_or_create(vendor=vendor, e=element,
                                                                         self_description=self_description, rfi=round,
                                                                         vendor_response=current_scoring_round)

            attachment, _ = Attachments.objects.get_or_create(vendor=vendor, path=attachment, rfi=round)

            element_attachment, _ = ElementsAttachments.objects.get_or_create(e=element, attachment=attachment,
                                                                              rfi=round,
                                                                              vendor_response=current_scoring_round)

            rfi_part_status, _ = RfiParticipationStatus.objects.update_or_create(vendor=vendor, rfi=round,
                                                                                 pc=parent_category.first(),
                                                                                 defaults={
                                                                                     'last_vendor_response': current_scoring_round}
                                                                                 )

        return self
```

**data sample**

```
"Parent Category": "SERVICES ",
        "Category": [
            {
                "S2P Services": [
                    {
                        "General": [
                            {
                                "Element Name": "Breadth of Implementation Services",
                                "Description": "Please describe what is ",
                                "Scoring Scale": "0. We've not yet really o",
                                "Self-Score": null,
                                "Self-Description": null,
                                "Attachments/Supporting Docs and Location/Link": null,
                                "SM score": null,
                                "Analyst notes": null
                            },
                            {
                                "Element Name": "Depth of Services Capabilities",
                                "Description": "Describe the depth o",
                                "Scoring Scale": "0. We've not yet really ",
                                "Self-Score": null,
                                "Self-Description": null,
                                "Attachments/Supporting Docs and Location/Link": null,
                                "SM score": null,
                                "Analyst notes": null
                            },
                          .....
                         and hundreds of such blocks
```

Comment: Did you try running this under `cProfile` ?

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim I have no idea what you're talking about. Im using  a standard  `create` method in the DRF serializer.

Comment: Did you profile your application?

Comment: What do you mean by profiling application?

Comment: I was talking about https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html

Comment: No, I didn't even know about that possibility, so I didn't use it in the project.

Comment: Do I need to use this module with a function that calls the POST method in my project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214104/discussion-between-shiplu-mokaddim-and-jekson).